# Error en: document.getElementById("cadena").value;

Tags: javascript, string

Quiero hacer un programa que simplemente sustituya las T por U en cualquier cadena. Pero la sintaxis de document.getElementById("cadena").value; me está dando problema, la consola me marca que el error está ahí, pero no tengo ni idea de cual es el motivo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      var cadena = document.getElementById("cadena").value.toUpperCase();
      var cadenafinal = "";
      function procesaCadena() {
        for (let char in cadena) {
          if (char === "T") {
            cadenafinal += `cadenafinal+${"U"}`;
          } else {
            cadenafinal += `cadenafinal+${char}`;
          }
        } //for
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cadenafinal;
        console.log(cadenafinal);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Desafio de Reemplazar las T por U de cualquier cadena</h1>
    <h3>Por ejemplo: "TTTTUT" --> "UUUUUU" || "GCAT" --> "GCAU"</h3>
    <p>
      Insertar una cadena:
      <input type="text" id="cadena" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" onClick="procesaCadena();">
        Transforma Cadena
      </button>
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que intentas hacer un `getElementById()` cuando el **DOM** *aún no está completamente cargado*.

Tienes dos soluciones:

1. **Esperar a que se carge**. Y para ello puedes encerrar todo el codigo que necesites inicializar con getElementByID() dentro de esta instrucción, que usa el evento [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) que controla cuando se ha cargado el documento:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {})
```

En este caso solamente parece que sea esta línea:

```
var cadena = document.getElementById("cadena").value.toUpperCase();
```

2. **Mover todo el `<script></script>` al final del HTML**, preferentemente antes del `</body>`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de la primera solución:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var cadena = document.getElementById("cadena").value.toUpperCase();
    })
      var cadenafinal = "";
      function procesaCadena() {
        for (let char in cadena) {
          if (char === "T") {
            cadenafinal += `cadenafinal+${"U"}`;
          } else {
            cadenafinal += `cadenafinal+${char}`;
          }
        } //for
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cadenafinal;
        console.log(cadenafinal);
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Desafio de Reemplazar las T por U de cualquier cadena</h1>
  <h3>Por ejemplo: "TTTTUT" --> "UUUUUU" || "GCAT" --> "GCAU"</h3>
  <p>
    Insertar una cadena:
    <input type="text" id="cadena" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" onClick="procesaCadena();">
        Transforma Cadena
      </button>
  </p>
  <p id="result"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero sigue sin funcionar, ahora hay error en la llamada a la función procesaCadena cuando pulso el botón creado con HTML: Uncaught ReferenceError: procesaCadena is not defined

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: procesaCadena is not defined

Comment: Es curioso, con la segunda solución si que funciona bien (poniéndolo al final del documento todo)... ya me miraré la primera otro rato, he de irme, saludoss

Comment: @RHAAPHAA Ya he entendido lo que ha pasado. He actualizado mi respuesta. Tu solución aun tiene un error pues has duplicado el `var cadena` tanto fuera como dentro de la función, y mejor que elimines el de fuera pues realmente no lo necesitas a menos que se ejecute la función (a menos que quieras que sea más global para otras funciones, en cuyo caso mis dos soluciones serian válidas). Saludos

Comment: Exacto!! A pesar de eso ese código funcionó como deseaba. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al final, la solución es esta, este código funciona. Agradezco haberme mostrado esta opción: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {})

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--   -->
    <script>
      //document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      
      var cadenafinal = "OOO->";
      function procesaCadena() {
        var cadena = document.getElementById("cadena").value.toUpperCase();
        var cadenafinal = "OOO->";
        //for (let char in cadena) {
        for (i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
          if (cadena.charAt(i) === "T") {
            cadenafinal = cadenafinal.concat("U");
          } else {
            cadenafinal = cadenafinal.concat(cadena.charAt(i));
          }
        } //for
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cadenafinal;
        console.log(cadenafinal);
        console.log(cadena);
      }
      // });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Desafio de Reemplazar las T por U de cualquier cadena</h1>
    <h3>Por ejemplo: "TTTTUT" --> "UUUUUU" || "GCAT" --> "GCAU"</h3>
    <p>
      Insertar una cadena:
      <input type="text" id="cadena" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="procesaCadena();">
        Transforma Cadena
      </button>
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar el onClick por onclick en el button, tu código script debes colocar al final, andes del cierre de la etiqueta . Puedes interar con for...of para obtener cada elemento de la cadena.

```js
      function procesaCadena() {
      
           var cadena = document.getElementById("cadena")
                                    .value.toUpperCase();
           var cadenafinal = "";
          
          for ( char of cadena ) {
              if (char === "T") {
                cadenafinal += "U";
              } else {
                cadenafinal += char;
              }
        } //for
        
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cadenafinal;
        //console.log(cadenafinal);
        
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Desafio de Reemplazar las T por U de cualquier cadena</h1>
    <h3>Por ejemplo: "TTTTUT" --> "UUUUUU" || "GCAT" --> "GCAU"</h3>
    <p>
      Insertar una cadena:
      <input type="text" id="cadena" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="procesaCadena();">
        Transforma Cadena
      </button>
    </p>
    <p id="result">antes</p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```